# Sign up and confirm a Cognito user

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-sdk-go

How can I programmatically confirm a Cognito user without knowing its confirmation code? I can create the user using `Signup()` but when I call `AdminInitiateAuth()` to try to get a session value, I get the `UserNotConfirmedException`. To respond to the challenge, I try to call `AdminRespondToAuthChallenge()` but that requires a session parameter. Seems like a bit of a catch-22. I just need to create a confirmed user without any intervention from the user himself.